# Which parameters should I consider to choose safety capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, pcb, high-voltage, mains, safety

I know the X and Y capacitors, how they are connected and why they are used but I am not sure about selection criteria and how they are exactly affecting the signal. I would appreciate with some help and explanation.

Comment: They affect signals in the same way that normal capacitors do. They are also selected on the same basis; capacitance and voltage withstand are primary objectives and, on some applications you might be interested in the dielectric losses. So, what has this question got specifically to-do with X and Y capacitors?

Comment: I couldn`t get the connection between common-mode noise and safety. They are called safety capacitors but what unclear for me is, the purpose of used in terms of safety or is it used for both reasons? Generally, I do not understand the concept. @Andyaka

Comment: There is no connection here between common-mode noise and safety except that X or Y rated capacitors can achieve both when connected to live / neutral and earth. You can use normal capacitors to get common-mode noise reduction but, that wouldn't be allowed on lines that are live where the failure of a capacitor can either cause a shock hazard or a fire. X and Y capacitors are designed not to cause fires and shock people in these circumstances.